# Newbie DB question : is it possible to shrink or clean a postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, size

I found out that my postgresql database is behaving weirdly. The disk was full yesterday and the database size is around 140 GB. I extended it by 20 GB to be able to troubleshoot as linux is refusing to do anything. I listed the databases and rtsm was 108 GBs also /var/lib/pgsql/13/data/base is full and contains files that are up to 1GB.

```
rtsm | rtsm  | UTF8 | en_ZM.UTF-8 | en_ZM.UTF-8 | =Tc/rtsm +| 108 GB  | pg_default |
```

the problem is when I listed the tables, I could not find any one that is using too much space, the largest one was like 800 Mb.

Am I missing something here?

PS: I used the VACUUM operation to reclaim space and I know it's not suitable to my case.

Comment: First, VACUUM doesn't reclame (all) disk space, check the manual. But second, when your tables don't take all the space, it must be something else. Did you check the indexes? And logfiles? Or whatever?

Comment: If you are on a Unix-like operating system, use `du` to check which directory contains how much. Depending on the result, you can proceed.

Comment: What is the sum of all those table sizes which are each <= 800MB?  For all we know based on what you have told us, it is 108GB.  It would only take ~150 tables, which is not an extreme number.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to check.

1. Tables can accrue dead rows. Vacuum will only mark those as reusable. End pages that are all dead are returned to OS. So you won't always claim space back this way. The extension pgstattuple is pretty good at showing this information. It scans all pages so can be resource intensive. Vacuum full will rewrite your table removing all dead space, but this locks it for the duration. The extension pg_repack will do this and maintain access. Both of these are resource intensive.
2. Index bloat. This is effectively the same as above. pgstattuple will show you the same information about them. Re-indexing will reclaim dead space within them.